# Using Cauchy Riemanns equation to show analyticity if unable to split up into real and imaginary part.

Tags: complex-analysis

For example in the cases

$f(z)=e^z / z$ , or $f(z)=z|z|^2$

how do I go about splitting the function up into a real and imaginary part so I can use Cauchy Riemann to check for analyticity?

Comment: Actually you don't have to use Cauchy Riemann if directly dealing with the difference quotient $\Delta f/\Delta z$ is simpler.

Comment: Hi Vim, could you clarify on this?

Comment: roughly speaking just treat it as real variable derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $e^z=e^x\cos(y)+ie^x \sin(y)$ and $1/z=(x-iy)/(x^2+y^2)$.

Comment: yes ofcourse, thanks alot

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.

Comment: While it works for splitting up into real and imaginary parts, I am unsure this is the best approach, since the partial derivative with respect to x results this mess: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(xe%5Excosy%2Bye%5Exsiny)%2F(x%5E2%2By%5E2)+partial+derivative+with+respect+to+x

Comment: I'm not certain as to what you mean by the "best approach."  if you want to decompose into real and imaginary parts, then this post provides a way to do so.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify, the best approach to show if the function is analytic or not

Comment: We can use the fact that $e^z$ is entire, $z$ is entire, and so $\frac{e^z}{z}$ is analytic for all $z\ne0$ since the quotient, $f/g$, of analytic functions $f$ and $g$ is also an analytic function for $g\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

A general case is $f=u+iv$ where $u={\bf Re\,}f=\dfrac12(f+\overline{f})$ and $u={\bf Im\,}f=\dfrac{1}{2i}(f-\overline{f})$. For instance $f(z)=z|z|^2$, then
$$u=\dfrac12(f+\overline{f})=\dfrac12(z|z|^2+\overline{z}|z|^2)=x(x^2+y^2)$$

Comment: Thank you for that input, I was not aware of that fact. However, could you expand on how you arrived at your answer? I am unsure of the absolute value of z^2

Comment: `\Re` $\Re$ and `\Im` $\Im$ are nice shortcuts

Comment: Ok. But I like those bold characters!